# Any way to pull/update all subrepos?

Tags: mercurial, subrepos, mercurial-subrepos

I'm looking into the viability of switching from svn to mercurial for my organization, but there's one hangup I can't seem to find a solution for.

Is there any way to pull and update a repo and all subrepos without manually pulling and updating each one?

I'd like to switch to mercurial, but if that's not possible then it's a no-go for us.

Edit: Good god I must be tired today... two questions on SO for which I find the answers minutes after asking...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Somehow missed this, and found it right after asking the question:
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/OnsubExtension

Comment: Yep, that's how you do it :)  Also, if you have mixed subrepos (some Mercurial, some Git, some Svn), you can run things like:

`hg onsub -t hg "hg pull -u"`
`hg onsub -t git "git pull"`

Answer (score 3):

You can define a simple shell alias like the following

```
alias hgsub='find . -name ".hg" -type d | grep -v "\./\.hg" | \
xargs -n1 dirname | xargs -n1 -iREPO hg -R REPO '
```

and then do

```
hgsub tip
hgsub pull -u
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alterantive, a batch script might help:

```
@echo off
for /D %%d in (*) do (
  if exist %%d\.hg (
    echo Verzeichnis %%d
    cd %%d
    hg pull -u
    echo ----------------------------------------------
    cd ..  
  )
)
pause
```

Comment: This script is non-portable, only works for Microsoft's windows and dos.